# Can i use classes to change css variables?

Tags: css, css-variables

Can I use classes to change CSS variables in SCSS file?
it works but I want to know if it's the right way to do it:

```
.header {
  --transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  transform: var(--transform);
  &--hide {
     --transform: translate(-50%, -84px);
  }
  &--show {
     --transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  }
}

// instead of this:

.header {
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  &--hide {
     transform: translate(-50%, -84px);
  }
  &--show {
     transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.
I tried it and it works, I'm using it for a navbar animation when I scroll up the navbar slide down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you override in your class the css variable like that:

```css
:root {
  --test: red;
}    
.header {    
  --test: green;
  color: var(--test);       
}
```

```html
<div class="header">abc</div>
```

**Note::** But I can't imagine a use case right now!?

Comment: thank you. I'm using it for a navbar animation when I scroll up the navbar slide down